# Why do some shiny-apps exit without log?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app running under shiny-server on a Ubuntu machine that keeps crashing at a specific event (selecting DT row).

I have this error messages in my browser's console

```
The application unexpectedly exited.

Diagnostic information is private. Please ask your system admin for permission if you need to check the R logs.
```

Still in my log folder (`/var/log/shiny-server`), I can't find the log of this specific app (although I see other apps' logs).

Why? Should I add any line of code to force printing the log?

Comment: Does your "shiny" user have writing rights in all relevant folders?

Comment: as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377437/accessing-error-log-in-shiny-server-deployed-on-aws-instance you could add sanitize_errors false to the siny-server.conf to actually see what's causing the problem

Comment: Did you end up finding any solution? I have an app that crashes, leaves no debugging info except for the useless Javascript console information.