# Running app successful in R studio but not in Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

My operation system is ubuntu.

I run a shiny app successfully in rstudio.

I have copied all files in the shiny server file. But when I try to run the app from shiny server I see in browser this error:

```
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

However when I go to logs I can't find log for the specific app.

Is there any workaround for that kind of issues?

Comment: maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377437/accessing-error-log-in-shiny-server-deployed-on-aws-instance

Comment: @MLavoie thanks for your answer. I found the same but I found the file shiny-server.conf in 3 different files. In which path should I replace this and also how can I restart shiny server (needs only a ubuntu system restart and it is ok?)

Comment: you could use "sudo service shiny-server restart" to restart and if I remember correctly (well that is the one I changed) you set the one located in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

Comment: Use absolute path while setting working directory. Also check your [user permissions](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/).

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'm putting this as an answer. Are all of the packages your app needs installed on the server?

Logs are not stored if the R process end successfully, and if I remember right that includes when packages are not installed.

From the [Shiny Server Configuration Guide](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-error-logs)

> A log file will be created for each R process when it is started.
>   However, if a process closes successfully, the error log associated
>   with that process will be automatically deleted. The only error log
>   files that will remain on disk are those associated with R processes
>   that did not exit as expected.
>
> You can override this behavior using the preserve_logs configuration
>   option. If you set preserve_logs true; in your configuration file,
>   Shiny Server will never delete the logs from your R processes,
>   regardless of their exit code. Be aware that this will cause log files
>   to accumulate very quickly on a busy server. This setting is only
>   recommended for debugging purposes; if it were to be enabled on a
>   production server, you would need to pay close attention to the
>   rotation and archiving of logs to prevent your file system becoming
>   overwhelmed with log files.